# How to verify if an HTML attribute contains an absolute or a relative URL using Protractor?

Tags: node.js, protractor

I'm using Protractor to test a web application and I've noticed that whenever I try to read an `href` attibute, Protractor treats the value as an absolute URL. This prevents me from verifying that the URL rendered by my application is indeed absolute.

Let's say I want to have an absolute URL, including the domain in my meta tags:

```
<link rel="next" href="https://www.example.com/path-to-page">
```

It turns out that when I read this element in Protractor, it doesn't matter what the actual value is, I still get an absolute URL.

Let's say the back-end (https://www.example.com) actually renders the following tag:

```
<link rel="next" href="/path-to-page">
```

accessing it in Protractor using

```
element(by.css('link[rel="next"]')).getAttribute('href')
```

yields `https://www.example.com/path-to-page` and not `/path-to-page`, which is the actual value when I view the page source using the browser or `curl`.

I find this approach overzealous. It can hide actual bugs. Is this a bug or a feature? What's the best way to get the actual path present in the attribute?

I've found [this issue on Github](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2735) but it was closed with a comment suggesting that the reporter seeks help on Stack Overflow.

Keep in mind that I don't just want to check the path part of the URL. I want to confirm that the attribute does indeed contain everything. The protocol, the domain, the path. If my back-end renders it differently, Protractor still pretends that it's correct because it figures out the domain based on the context of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `browser.executeScript();` with Javascript will give you the actual href, and not the full link that Protractor (annoyingly) resolves.
Example:

```
let elem = element(by.css('link[rel="next"]'));
let url = await browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].getAttribute("href");',elem);
```